# Dynamically populate page with links to document libraries

Tags: document-library, metadata, hyperlink

The business where I work wants to move from one library with multiple client folders to one library per client. 
To ease in administration I want to create a page that displays hyperlinks to all libraries with a specific 'client' tag dynamically.

I have looked and can't find anything to achieve this, although I'm very much a novice with SharePoint. Any advice on the method I should use or how I could go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you using SharePoint 2013 / O365 you can leverage Search.  Create a page with a Search Results Web Part or Content By Search Web part (depending on if you have Foundation/Standard or Enterprise).  Edit the Search criteria to only target document libraries in your site.

If you are storing libraries across sites, then I suggest using a content type and then configure your query to return those.

If you are running SharePoint 2010 you can still use the Search Results Web Part - but it's not quite as easy.  You also have the Content Query Web Part you can use as well.

Search in 2013 can further be customized with Display templates - which are fairly easy to learn to create some basic layouts.  In 2010 it's harder as you have to work with XSL/XSLT and with the Content Query Web Part you need to export the webpart, then modify the files, and add and re-deploy it.

Comment: A Table of Contents web part would work too

Comment: Good call on ToC - I don't use that much so forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

The DON'Ts

1. Don't create multiple library one library per client.
2. Don't create one library and add multiple folders, one for each client.

The DO's

1. Create one library, create a column of type **Choice (menu to choose from)**, call it "Client" and make it a required field.
2. Create a page and add a Web Part to this one library and modify the view to group all the documents by this new "Client" column.
3. Now whenever a new document is added to the library and tagged with the correct client name from the list, your page will automatically show the document under the related client.

Comment: There may be thousands of documents we're talking about here, separating into separate libraries would work to get around large list thresh holds. A blanket don't do it statement without knowing more information is unfounded.